# Connect to RavenDB using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ravendb

I am using node to connect to RavenDB
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ravendb 
but when try to create a connection, at this step
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcFZ9.png 
I dont know what to put in `database url` and `default database name`
and I put 
`database url`=localhost:5000
`default database name`=test (my db name is test)

and the console show this error `Failed to load http://localhost:5000/topology?name=test`
how can I create this connection.

EDIT
I config the program 
this is my file app.js
`const DocumentStore = require('ravendb').default;
const store = DocumentStore.create('localhost:5000', 'test');
store.initialize();
const session = store.openSession();`

when I run this file with node, it show the error: (but it will compile fine if I delete the line
`const session = store.openSession();` so I think the problem is somewhere around the session.
Error log:

`"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.2\bin\runnerw.exe" D:\nodejs\node.exe D:\nodeProject\demoraven\app.js
Unhandled rejection ee: Node localhost:5000 is down
    at d.finally.catch.e (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\ravendb\lib\ravendb-node.js:2:52762)
    at tryCatcher (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\nodeProject\demoraven\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for pointers on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know what to put in database url and default database name and
>   I put

Database URL is the HTTP address where you're running a Raven Server. You can download Raven and run it locally. Or if you're just testing, you can connect to the playground server located at http://4.live-test.ravendb.net

For DefaultDatabase, that's the database you want to connect to. If you already have created a database, use that name. Otherwise, put in any name, and it will be created for you.

So, to sum up, your code should look like this:

```
const dbUrl = "http://4.live-test.ravendb.net"; // Alternately, if you're running Raven Server locally, use http://localhost:8080 
const store = DocumentStore.create(dbUrl, "MyTestingDatabase");
store.initialize();
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but please see my edited post, I have some other problems

Comment: You're getting an error about fetching topology. That's OK. Raven may be checking if your database is part of a cluster. (If it's not, you may receive a 404, IIRC). In other words, don't worry about the topology fetch error. Are you still be able to use the database despite this error?

Comment: no, it show the line:
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: RavenDB just released first stable for NodeJS. I'd suggest giving it a try: https://ayende.com/blog/183265-A/ravendb-4-0-node-js-client-rtm

Answer (score 0):

as @Judah Himango  said , you can test whether your code is able to connect to revendb database using url provided by him .

I think you are using the wrong port to connect to ravendb , i.e you should set `database url=localhost:8080` instead of `localhost:5000` as the default port of ravendb is `8080`

Comment: that is the port I config when I install the RavenDB, I go to the url `localhost:5000` and it loaded fine